# Script in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch, and currently studying the scriptting in ES.It would be really great if anyone who knows scripting in elasticsearch can put some light over scripting and its use in ES ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can start with reading elasticsearch documentation. Scripting is covered in the following topics on elasticsearch web site:

- [General information](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/scripting.html)
- [Script Fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/script-fields.html)
- [Using script to filter the results](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/script-filter.html)
- [Using script to sort the results](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/sort.html)
- [Using scripts in facets](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/index.html) (see individual facet documentation pages)

If after reviewing these pages, you still have concreate questions about scripting, don't hesitate to ask them in elasticsearch mailing list or on stackoverflow. Following guidelines on the [Help](http://www.elasticsearch.org/help/) page of elasticsearch website will significantly improve your chances of getting quick and useful answer.